# IE8. Why typeof behaves different in child windows?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, underscore.js

I'm having an issue understanding the mechanics of *typeof* in IE8.

I have the following JavaScript code in "parent.html":

```
var myNewWindow = window.open('child.html');
myNewWindow.sayhi = function() {
    alert('Hi!');
}
```

In parent.html we open a JavaScript console (F12). We test the type and looks correct.

```
typeof myNewWindow.sayhi      "function"
```

But if I open a console and do some tests in the child window, the results are somehow weird.

```
typeof this.sayhi             "object"
```

The thing is that the "object" can be called. *this.sayhi()* shows an alert.

Even underscoreJS gets confused

```
_.isFunction(this.sayhi)       false
```

Can someone explain why a function present in window(this) but declared in outer window is not recognized as a function but as an object by IE8?

By the way, some say I should look the answer in:
[typeof window.close is different for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457836/typeof-window-close-is-different-for-ie)

Guess what? It still says that this thing is an object:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(this.sayhi)          '[object Object]'
```

Comment: Because IE always needs to be a pain.

Comment: Related: http://www.kilometer0.com/blog/code/internet-explorer-ie-cross-window-javascript-object-typeof-bug/

Comment: In JavaScript Functions are Objects, so there's nothing wrong with it reporting it that way. What's out of the ordinary is IE8 in general :) This has been discussed before though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457836/typeof-window-close-is-different-for-ie

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv so why every browser even IE8 returns "function" when querying a locally declared function?

Comment: Related: [typeof returning “unknown” in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982739/typeof-returning-unknown-in-ie) and [Internet Explorer 7/8 and window functions are empty objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619826/internet-explorer-7-8-and-window-functions-are-empty-objects)

Comment: That's inherently related to quirks in IE8 implementation. @jbabey gave you a pretty detailed explanation about why this happens.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv: It *is* wrong because all callable objects - even if they are host objects! - [must return `"function"`](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.3) (at least in ES5, that was not true for ES3 unfortunately)

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought the irony was clear. My intention was of directing him to the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be due to the fact that `typeof` internally checks if the item being tested inherits from the current window's `Function` object. Since the function was created in another window, and inherited from a different `Function` object, the check fails.

To prove this, in the console of the child window type:

`this.sayhi instanceof Function` > you should get `false`

`this.sayhi instanceof window.opener.Function` > you should get `true`

[Related article](http://www.kilometer0.com/blog/code/internet-explorer-ie-cross-window-javascript-object-typeof-bug/)

On a side note, you should see this same problem with all native types (`Function`, `Array`, etc)

Comment: So... correct me if I'm wrong. typeof actually calls instanceof and then gives you an output, right?

Comment: Sort of. They both rely on the same internal properties. http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3

Comment: @AdrianSalazar: No, it does not. This answer seems to have confused them - it is true what it says about `instanceof`, but unrelated to your `typeof` problem.

Comment: [HasInstance](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.5.3) is the internal function they both rely on. It checks the prototype chain for matching objects. Like I said, since the function was not created in the prototype chain of the child window, the check fails.